# Ignore inheritance during COPY

Tags: database, postgresql, inheritance

Let's say we have a parent and a child table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name            text,
    population      float,
    elevation       int     -- in feet
);

CREATE TABLE capitals (
    state           char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

Now, when I insert any row on child `capitals` it is expected to insert the same on the parent table `cities` as well.

I am using a migration tool, which uses the `COPY` command to populate data from the source to the target.

The rows are duplicated in the parent table because there are 2 inserts.

- COPY command of itself
- COPY command of its children

when it inserts the rows into the child table using COPY, the tables are inserted into the parent table as well.

I want to insert some data into the child table using the `COPY` command without inserting them into the parent table.

Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows are not duplicated. If you insert into `capitals`, nothing is inserted into `cities`. But when you `SELECT` from `cities`, PostgreSQL will also show the results from `capitals`. In fact,

```
SELECT * FROM cities;
```

actually performs

```
SELECT name, population, elevation
FROM ONLY cities
UNION ALL
SELECT name, population, elevation
FROM ONLY capitals;
```

You can use `ONLY` to avoid that:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY cities;
```

But if you don't want the default behavior of table inheritance, it might be best not to use the feature at all.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `COPY only FROM` for my use case.